# Swift 3 using the value from pickerview in webview url

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to add a variable value from pickerview inside my webview URL

```
 var ["1","2", "3"] 

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            storedName = names[row]
            pickerViewButton.text = storedName

            print("\(Myvar.text)")
            let url = URL (string: "http://examplesite.com/search.php?name=\(myvar.text)")
            let request = URLRequest(url: url as URL!);
            Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest);
        }
```

So for example my url will end up like this "http://examplesite.com/search.php?name=1" the first value of the array above picked with the pickerView.

However I keep getting the following fatal error

"Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value "

edit 1:

```
storedName = names[row]
dropdownButtonLabel.text = storedName

let domainAPI = "http://examplesite.com/search.php?"
let request = URLRequest(url: url);
Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest);
let query = "name=\(storedName)"

if let queryPercentEncoded = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: domainAPI + queryPercentEncoded) {
    print(url)
}
```

this is what I have right now

Comment: try `let url = URL(string: "http ://examplesite.com/search.php?name=\(storedName)")`

Comment: `let request = URLRequest(url: url!)`

Comment: Also you should safely unwrap your url and casting from URLRequest to URLRequest makes non sense

Comment: Make sure you percent encode your URL query parameters

Comment: What's the String value of the storedName parameter? Does it contain invalid URL characters?

Comment: Is your webview outlet properly connected?

Comment: Does it have spaces on it? Do you now how to percentEncode it?

Comment: I need to see the picker array source elements. Does it crashes with just "1", "2", "3"?

Comment: You need to move your percent encoding to the top of your code `let domainAPI = "http://examplesite.com/search.php?"
let query = "name=\(storedName)"
if let queryPercentEncoded = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: domainAPI + queryPercentEncoded) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    Webview.loadRequest(request)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you percent encode your URL query parameters. You have do it as follow:

```
let domainAPI = "http://examplesite.com/search.php?"
let query = "name=\(storedName)"
if let queryPercentEncoded = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: domainAPI + queryPercentEncoded) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    Webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```